# Backdrop control in Windows 10 UWP doesn't blur

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app, blur, windows-10-universal

I am trying to add a Backdrop blur in my Windows 10 UWP app, however the blur effect doesn't work. I am using the code from [Windows UILabs Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsUIDevLabs/blob/6e8340684c5bca8d86ffa90f2d5fd142a876e7e9/SamplesCommon/SamplesCommon/BackDrop.cs), but the blur effect simply doesn't show. I also tried making my own simplified code, but that didn't work either (didn't throw any exceptions though). In the XAML, I am using

`<Grid x:Name="grid_blur" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,0,55" Height="100" Background="Transparent">
            <local:BackDrop BlurAmount="40" TintColor="Red"/>
</Grid>`

to add the Backdrop control itself.

I am using VS2015 Community Update 2, project target version is build 14295.

Does anyone have the same problem or am I simply missing something (or should I stop copy & pasting from github?). Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to be on the correct windows build for it to work - AFAIK it's not working in the very latest fast ring windows build, but it works on the one they released right during build.

Comment: I am on 14295.1000 on PC and on 14328.1000 on phone, the effect doesn't work on these...

Comment: It should work on 14295. Did you install the insider preview SDK as well?

Comment: Oh sorry, just checked on my PC and I am on 14316.1000 (wrote the comment from the phone). So the feature simply doesn't work on this build?
And yeah, I do have the insider preview SDK installed.

Comment: Yep it doesn't, as far as I know. But check https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsUIDevLabs/wiki/Last-Known-Good

Comment: So, after installing WM10 Emulator 14295 (and more than a hour trying to make it work), the blur works! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Awesome, glad to help out :)

Answer (score -1):

Don't know UILabs but you can also use Win2D to apply a blur effect. Please check the following article https://www.eternalcoding.com/?p=1911. In next version of UWP SDK, Windows Composition will provide you also a native way to perform Blur, Drop Shadow and Light effects.

Comment: Actually, the UILabs sample is using Win2D effects, the problem is that the control doesn't make the background blur (cannot tell if the blur effect itself doesn't work or if there is a problem with setting the Backdrop background as the blurred brush).
The code that is on UILabs Github is more-less the same as the one used in presentations from MS /build 2016 and is using the Composition stuff.